# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext asp core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am a new ASP Core developer.
I want to make a sign-in method and update my database but I get

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext asp core

I tried a lot of things, but nothing works.

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<StudentSelectionContext>();
       
        services.AddMvc();
        
       
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(option => {
                option.LoginPath = "/User/LogIn";
                option.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
                option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
    }
```

and that my StudentSelectionContext

```cs
 public StudentSelectionContext()
    {
    }

    public StudentSelectionContext(DbContextOptions<StudentSelectionContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FinalDistribution> FinalDistribution { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InfoTable> InfoTable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StudnetGpa> StudnetGpa { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StuSelection> StuSelection { get; set; }

 
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
    }
```

so what is the problem?

Comment: Which database do you intent to use ? Here's a sample method u need to add to your startup.cs to work with PostGres, along with installing Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Nuget package  :-         
       services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConnection")));

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `DataBase Provider` while using `AddDbContext`.

You could refer this [Database Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) to find the available database provider.

For development mode, you may try SQL Server Express, and you could try code below:

```
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The ConnectionString is configured in `appsettings.json`